# How to make PDFMiner Six detect bullet points (including alphanumeric bullets) when parsing documents?

Tags: python, pdf, package, detection, pdf-parsing

I am currently using PDFMiner.six to parse documents for me, but would like it to be able to detect bullet points (including alphanumeric bullets like "a.", "i.", "1."). For now, it only treats them as characters, but I was wondering if I am missing some functionality in PDFMiner.six that would allow me to more easily determine when a bullet or group of bullets appears.

I'm currently under the assumption that I'm just going to have to write an algorithm to find these special characters and substrings at the start of each block, but am fairly new to this and would love to be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Whether or not **characters** function as bullet points or numbered lists, etc. is something that your code must detect by "understanding" the context and usually must be based on some page layout analysis. There is nothing in PDF itself that exposes these things as anything else than just normal characters. In the general case, small vector graphics or PDF inline images are also used as bullet points often enough, and this breadth of spectrum is beyond packages like pdfminer, pypdf and the like.